# Integration of complicated equation

Tags: integration

I was looking at a Wolfram Mathworld article about bean curves: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BeanCurve.html

And it states that the area enclosed by the curve of

$$x^4+x^2y^2+y^4=ax(x^2+y^2)$$ is

$$A=\sqrt{2}a^2\int_0^1\sqrt{x\left(1-x+\sqrt{1+(2-3x)x}\right)}\text{d}x=\frac{7\pi a^2}{12\sqrt{3}}$$

Although a brief calculation shows that the area enclosed by the curve is $$A=\sqrt{2}a^2\int_0^1\sqrt{x\left(1-x+\sqrt{1+(2-3x)x}\right)}\text{d}x$$ I have no clue how the integration, in which $$A=\frac{7\pi a^2}{12\sqrt{3}}$$
, works.
I would like to know how!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha for about $5 a month will show you steps to an unlimited number of exercises.  Considering this question could easily take 30 minutes and likely more, why not use the premium access and view the steps?

Comment: I've tried running this in WolframAlpha and various other integration calculators but it could not figure out the integration.

Answer (score 1):

use polar coordinates to evaluate the area.
$$r^4(\sin^4(\theta)+\cos^4(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\theta))=ar^3\cos(\theta)$$
$$r=\frac{a\cos(\theta)}{\sin^4(\theta)+\cos^4(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\theta)}$$
$$\frac{A}{a^2}=\frac{1}{2a^2}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}r^2 d\theta$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos^2(\theta)}{(\sin^4(\theta)+\cos^4(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\theta))^2} d\theta$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos^2(\theta)}{(\sin^4(\theta)+\cos^4(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\theta))^2} d\theta$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos^2(\theta)}{(1-\frac{1}{4}\sin^2(2\theta))^2} d\theta$$
$$=8\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{2\cos^2(\theta)}{(4-sin^2(2\theta))^2} d\theta$$
$$=8\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{1+\cos(2\theta)}{(4-\sin^2(2\theta))^2} d\theta$$
$$=4\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1+\cos(\phi)}{(4-\sin^2(\phi))^2} d\phi$$
$$=4\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1}{(4-\sin^2(\phi))^2} d\phi$$
$$=16\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1}{(8-2\sin^2(\phi))^2} d\phi$$
$$=16\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1}{(7+\cos(2\phi))^2} d\phi$$
$$=8\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{(7+\cos(\alpha))^2} d\alpha$$
$$=16\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1}{(7+\cos(\alpha))^2} d\alpha$$
$$=16*\frac{7\sqrt3}{288}*\tan^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\tan(\frac{\alpha}{2}))|_0^{\pi}$$
$$=\frac{7\sqrt3}{18}*\frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$A=\frac{7\pi a^2}{12\sqrt3}$$
change of variables: $\phi=2\theta$ and $\alpha=2\phi$

Comment: (+1) Maybe you could explain what happens every 3 to 6 MathJax lines?

Comment: Could you explain how $$4\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1+\cos(\phi)}{(4-\sin^2(\phi))^2} d\phi$$  
$$=4\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1}{(4-\sin^2(\phi))^2} d\phi$$  works?

Comment: $\frac{\cos(\phi)}{(4-\sin^2(\phi))^2}$ is antisymmetric about the line $x=\pi/2$ , so its integral is 0.

Comment: Thank you. How can the last line be explained, which is $$\tan^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\tan(\frac{\alpha}{2}))|_0^{\pi}= \frac{\pi}{2}$$   ?

Comment: $\tan^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}tan\frac{\pi}{2})=\tan^{-1}(+\infty)=\frac{\pi}{2}$